# How to install pyspark & spark for learning purpose on a laptop with limited resources?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata, pyspark

I have a windows 7 laptop with 6GB RAM . What is the most RAM/resource efficient way to install pyspark & spark on this laptop just for learning purpose. I don't want to work on actual big data but small dataset is ideal since this is just for learning pyspark & spark in general. I would prefer the latest version of Spark.

FYI: I don't have hadoop installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've basically got three options:

- Build everything from source
- Install Virtualbox and use a pre-built VM like Cloudera Quickstart
- Install Docker and find a suitable container

Getting everything up and running when you choose to build from source can be a pain. You've got to install the JDK, build hadoop and spark (both of which require you to install additional software to build them), set up a bunch of environment variables and then pray that didn't mess anything up.

VMs are nice, particularly the one from Cloudera, but you'll often be stuck with an older version of Spark and it might be tight with the resources you described.

**I'd go with Docker.**

Once you've got docker installed, it becomes very easy to try Spark (and lots of other technologies). My favorite containers for playing around use ipython or jupyter notebooks.

Install Docker:

- https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/

Jupyter Notebook Python, Spark, Mesos Stack

- https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that you are going to have to allocate a certain amount of memory for the VM and the remaining memory still has to operate Windows.  Windows 7 requires a minimum of 1 GB for a 32-bit OS or 2 GB for a 64-bit OS.  So likely you are only going to wind up with around 4 GB of RAM for running the VM, which is not much.

Assuming you are 64-bit, note that Cloudera requires a minimum of 4 GB RAM to run CDH 5, but if you want to run Cloudera Express, you need 8 GB.

Running Docker from Windows will require you to use boot2docker, which keeps the entire VM in memory.  It uses minimal memory (like around 27 MB) to run, so you should be fine there.  A MUCH better solution than running VirtualBox!

Another option to consider would be to spin up a free machine on something like Amazon Web Services (http://aws.amazon.com) or Google Cloud (http://cloud.google.com).  Particularly with the later, you can get a free trial amount of credits, which you could use to spin up a machine with more RAM than you would typically get with AWS.